# How to Sync same file on Computer, Drive and Android phone with read/write access?

Tags: microsoft-excel, laptop, sync, android, google-drive

**Hello,**

I am new to the data uploading and downloading to cloud services of google and Microsoft. I am having a problem in this aspect.

**Problem:**

I have a MS-Excel file on my Laptop(Windows 10), and i have a google drive account. Also, i have an android phone with same google account and Excel app installed on android to edit excel type files.

I have synced certain file on my laptop with the google drive (using Backup and Sync application of google installed on laptop).

Now, if i make any change in that file on laptop and save it. the same changes appear on the same synced file on google drive (syncing is ok between laptop and drive).

If i open the same file from my android phone (in google drive app), same changes appear in that file. But if i want to make some change in that file on android phone drive app, it open it to google sheets or Excel app on android. But here i have only read access, i can't write or edit the file on my android phone. If i want to edit, it says you have to save  a copy of that file on your phone. If i do that, it becomes another file on my android which is not same as original file on my laptop or drive. So any changes on new file won't be present on original file. (Syncing between android and drive and laptop is **not ok)**.

**What i want is that i have same file, which i can access on my laptop, drive, and android and edit that file and it gets synced automatically (if i make change on phone or laptop, as soon as they get internet, the file gets synced with the drive). So that, at any time, there is only one file on laptop, drive and phone at any time which is the latest modified file (modified by any of three).??**

Is it possible?? Please tell me how to do it if its possible??

Thanks..

Comment: I agree with the answer here. It sounds like editing an excel file often and on different devices is important to you. If that is the case then you’d need an office 365 subscription and you need to tie your devices to OneDrive. All the latest office apps have full integration with one drive and should do what you want. Google chose to make things difficult and Microsoft isn’t going to design their products to support google. So, it’s a matter of using the right technology for your needs. In fact, Excel on iOS integrates with just about every cloud service there is except google drive.

Comment: Yes, that might be the problem, even in android excel is able to integrate on a lot of cloud services but not google drive. But then, if there is something else like other than excel, there might come a need to rethink technology platform again.? Though i know now that for MS-Office products, OneDrive is the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into the "Details & Activity" and change "who has access" to "editor"

Also make sure you're using Google Docs and stuff to edit when your not on the computer

Answer (score 1):

I think onedrive is what you're looking for. https://onedrive.live.com/, its designed to work well with ms excel for obvious reasons.

Comment: Is there no way to use google drive in that sense?? the file accessed on drive by android phone is not allowed to edit even if i open that file on google sheets instead of Excel app on my android?? is their no way?